# Mac Book Pro 2012 model: My sharing name automatically changes

Tags: macbook-pro, sharing, macos

I have a mac book pro from 2013 (mid 2012 model) the only customisation I have done is install a bigger hard drive. Whenever I go into sharing settings the name of my computer to others is the serial number which makes using air drop confusing when trying to find my computer. I have tried changing it before but whenever my computer goes to sleep then I open it again it has changed back. Please help (I'm running El Capitan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make sure you're changing your computer name in the right place, follow these steps:

1. Go to System Preferences
2. Click on Sharing
3. In the Computer Name field, enter the name you want your computer to use.
4. Exit System Preferences

Now, assuming you were already doing that, you should reset your NVRAM.

**Reset your PRAM/NVRAM**

Older Macs had what's called Parameter RAM (PRAM), newer Macs use Non-Volatile Random-Access Memory (NVRAM). You should definitely reset this to try resolving your issue. Follow these steps:

1. **Shut down your machine.** Yes, a full shut down, not just logging out.
2. **Press the <kbd>power button</kbd> *and then* press the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> keys.** You have to make sure you press these keys before the gray screen appears or it won’t work.
3. **Hold those keys down** until your Mac reboots again and you here the startup chime.
4. **Let go of the keys and let your Mac reboot normally.**

**Note:** When you log back in you ***may*** need to readjust some of your system preferences (e.g. mouse speed, time and date/timezone, etc).